# Does my PC requires additional hardware to connect to Bluetooth headphones?

Tags: bluetooth

I am buying Bluetooth headphones for my Android phone and I'm wondering if my PC can connect to it too.

Does my PC require any additional hardware?

Comment: In order to get a decent and correct answer, could you provide more details on your computer? For example, if it's a laptop, you'd already have the bluetooth connector and would be set to use it.

Comment: Does your PC have a bluetooth adapter? Or does the headphone comes with one?

Comment: It's regular PC. I do not know if it has a bluetooth adapater. It has a wifi adapter it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PC will require a Bluetooth adapter. To find out if you currently have one:

### Windows

1. Go to `Device Manager` (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> in Windows 8+, or search `Device Manager` in the `Start Menu` for Windows 7)
2. Check in here if you have a category for `Bluetooth`. If so, you already have the required hardware.

[image]

### Mac OS X

1. Click the `Apple` menu.
2. Select `About This Mac`.
3. Click on the `More Info...` button.
4. Click on the `System Report...` button.
5. Look for Bluetooth from the sidebar on the left, underneath "Hardware."

### Linux

May vary between distributions, but you can check for an output to:

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
```

and it may reveal if you have an adapter already.

---

If you do not, you can use a simple USB adapter and pair with your headphones with that.